# Casting pointer differences in printing in c

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Consider the code:

```
int main() {
    char orange[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        orange[i] = 1;
    printf("orange: %d\n", *((char *)orange));        
    printf("orange: %d\n", *((int *)orange)); 
    return 0;
}
```

The first print statement gives me a value of `1`, but the second print statement gives me a value of `16843009`. What is the reason for the difference?

Comment: I would guess that the second statement is taking the whole list and treating it as one giant int. So it may be treating orange as one long binary number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second case, you casted it to `int` pointer. Hence assuming `int` to be `4` bytes on your system, doing `*((int *)orange)` will access `4` bytes starting from `orange[0]` to `orange[3]`.

Since you have all `1` in these address the hex notation of `orange[0]` to `orange[3]` will be `0x01010101` which is `16843009` in decimal.

Answer (score 5):

In the second one you are *aliasing* some adjacent `char` values as `int`. This is undefined according to the C standard; however a common result is that you will get the value of `int` which has the same bit-pattern as the bit-pattern of those `char` values concatenated.

In this case the value you are seeing is the decimal form of `0x01010101` .

It is undefined behaviour because of C99 6.5#7 which lists the valid type combinations which may be aliased, and `char` as `int` is not in the list.  (You *can* alias `int` as `char`, but not the other way around). [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84549/1505939) to get the Standard text.

There is also potential undefined behaviour because of *alignment requirements*. For example, some systems require that `int` only be accessed at addresses which are multiples of 4.

Comment: Hi @Matt, I didn't understand as why it is undefined behavior. It will be nice if you can explain it or give me some resource to read about it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to know int is a `4 bytes quantity`, char is a `1 byte`. 
When the machine read an integer, it will read consecutive 4 bytes. And read 1 byte for char.
In your case, you first declare an array orange[5], which is consecutive 5 bytes on the machine. And you assign 1 for each byte. So you will get something like this on your machine

```
0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001
```

And variable orange is a pointer pointing to the first byte. If you cast orange to `char *` and dereference it, the machine will try to read a char on this address (orange), so you will get

```
0000 0001
```

If you cast orange to int pointer, the machine will try to read 4 bytes starting from orange, so you will get this.

```
0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001
```

If you turn this binary number into decimal, you will get `16843009`

Hope it helps :)